# where are my downloaded google play apps? i cannot find them in apps on my surface

Tags: google-play-store

I have downloaded several apps from google play on my surface but they are no where to be found. I have tried search and poked around download files but nothing. Should it really be this hard? Seems ridiculous.

Comment: Did you even search online about your question or even here before posting the question? Please demonstrate that you have put in some effort to researching a solution or at least tell us what you have done, that helps us to provide more relevant answers.

Comment: Maybe, [next time](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Where+does+Play+Store+download+apps%3F) :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Play doesn't download .apk files to your phone but install the application. If you want to find the base.apk though you can find it in:

`/data/app/app.package.name`

however, it is off-limits to a non-root user. Your stock File Manager app won't let you browse that partition and third party browsers will return *Access Denied* when try to reach `/data` partition as non-root.

Comment: Yep, but there is still hope. `adb pull /data/app/PACKAGE` or any backup app in Play Store would do. :)

Comment: And it's `/data/app/<package_name>.apk` IIRC :) Exact name and location can be obtained using `adb shell "dumpsys package" | egrep -A99999 "Package \[<package_name_here>\]"` and check the first line containing the keyword `codePath` :)

Comment: @Izzy and `adb shell pm path PACKAGE` would be a shortcut too. :) Perhaps, `adb shell "dumpsys package PACKAGE" | egrep "codePath="`. Of course, who am I kidding with?

Comment: Many roads lead to Rome :) But your last command would dump *all* `.apk` files. The first one however is better than my "quick check", @Firelord ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've tried that, and got nothing back. Turns out I've had a typo in the package name #/ OK, so forget that: both work, but the first is easier :)

Comment: @Izzy And we both forgot the easiest one we suggest to others, `adb shell pm list packages -f PACKAGE`. :)

Comment: @Firelord It sounded like OP wanted to find the .apk **within** the phone and that's why I suggested in-device methods. Neither adb nor backup apps wouldn't work without root as well anyway.

Comment: ADB and those backup apps can fetch the APK with no problem. No root is required for that. :) Try it! That's why I wrote "*there is still hope*".

Comment: @Firelord It does? How though? Isn't both the backup app and ADB shell are just users? Shouldn't their demand to access another users data be denied?

Comment: @SarpSTA especially for backup purposes, ADB got elevated privileges (starting with ICS). "General info" is also considered "safe enough", as in order to use ADB the user must *authorize* it (at least once) *on the device itself*, which requires unlocking the screen. So that command sees nothing a normal user app could not obtain.

Comment: Because this answer does the job nicely, so I need not to explain anything here. Make sure you upvote this: [Get APK of installed app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11013175)

Comment: @Firelord It is only for `/data/app` right? Not `/data/data`. That'd be pretty unsafe.